# C# ASPX ASP.NET - Add & Delete Table Row

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

**My current setup:**
Form
Dropdown List (populated by SQL)
Users select an item from DDL, press the **[+ (add)]** button
SQL lookup on this items value
New row in a table, cells of input values based on SQL results
Last cell in row has a **[- (delete)]** button to remove that row
Users can do this multiple times, thus the table

eg.

> *DDL:*
>   [value:123] **[+]**
>
> *Table:*
>   | Row# | ID | Firstname |  Lastname | Delete |
>   | 1 | 123 | John | Smith | X |

**Better solution?** Tell me if you can think of a better way before moving on...

**The issue** is that I cannot find a way to dynamically add rows to a table using C# / ASP.

Preferably, I need some ASP functions to do this dynamically (or next best thing). I could settle for a Javascript Adhoc, but I was trying to avoid this as the data I need to add to a new table row is being fetched via SQL.

**Currently** this is my broken code thus far (just the stuff you need):

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Item>1</asp:Item>
    <asp:Item>2</asp:Item>
    <asp:Item>3</asp:Item>
</asp:DropDownList>

<input type="button" onClick="AddRow()" runat="server" />`

<asp:Table id="aTable" name="aTable">  
<asp:TableHeaderRow>  
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>1</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>2</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>3</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>4</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>5</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell>6</asp:TableHeaderCell>  
</asp:TableHeaderRow> 

</asp:Table>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void AddRow(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    Table table = new Table();  
    table.ID = "aTable";
    TableRow row = new TableRow();  
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();  
    table.Rows.Add(row);  
    cell.Text = "Test";  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
}
```

**Research** tells me about DataTables but from the looks of things these don't display as tables in a browser. I've also read a bunch of rubbish tutorials that don't work, so I'm here to ask the pro's at SO!

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be much better off using a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx). These can easily be set to an SQL datasource as in the examples.

It is also possible to not set a datasource in the aspx page and then in the page_load event you can do this sort of thing:

```
Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView.DataSource = Webservice.someMethodCall(param1, param2);
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

This approach also means that when the button is clicked the page_load event is triggered and the gridview will be updated.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm surprised you didn't set `runat="server"` at `asp:Table` tag.

```
<asp:Table id="aTable" name="aTable" runat="server">
```

Second, from the code behind, you can directly use `aTable` object.

```
protected void AddRow(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    TableRow row = new TableRow();  
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();  
    aTable.Rows.Add(row);  
    cell.Text = "Test";  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
    row.Cells.Add(cell);  
}
```

Third, there is a lot of resources to learn. Use Google.

Comment: Apologies, I did though I accidently forgot to include in the sample code I provided. Although the code didn't work, I appreciate the help but you didn't have to include the Google jab.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the GridView control. I personnally prefer the Telerik control suite.

Here is a link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-4

Answer (score 1):

Beaten by 3 minutes...but still.

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClick="AddRow" />
<asp:Table id="aTable" name="aTable" runat="server">  
    <asp:TableHeaderRow>  
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>1</asp:TableHeaderCell> 
    </asp:TableHeaderRow> 
</asp:Table>

protected void AddRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Text = "hello";
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    aTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```